# PS1 env variable does not work on mac

Tags: git, macros, ps1

I have a script(not written by myself) which shows the git branch/svn branch in my command prompt. Does anyone know why this would not work on mac? It works perfectly in linux.

From https://github.com/xumingming/dotfiles/blob/master/.ps1:

```
# Display ps1 with colorful pwd and git status
# Acording to Jimmyxu .bashrc
# Modified by Ranmocy
# --

if type -P tput &>/dev/null && tput setaf 1 &>/dev/null; then
    color_prompt=yes
else
    color_prompt=
fi

__repo () {
    branch=$(type __git_ps1 &>/dev/null && __git_ps1 | sed -e "s/^ (//" -e "s/)$//")
    if [ "$branch" != "" ]; then
        vcs=git
    else
        branch=$(type -P hg &>/dev/null && hg branch 2>/dev/null)
        if [ "$branch" != "" ]; then
            vcs=hg
        elif [ -e .bzr ]; then
            vcs=bzr
        elif [ -e .svn ]; then
            vcs=svn
        else
            vcs=
        fi
    fi
    if [ "$vcs" != "" ]; then
        if [ "$branch" != "" ]; then
            repo=$vcs:$branch
        else
            repo=$vcs
        fi
        echo -n "($repo)"
    fi
    return 0
}

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
# PS1='\[\e[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[01;34m\]\w\[\e[33;40m\]$(__repo)\[\e[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='\[\e[01;32m\]\u\[\e[00m\]:\[\e[01;34m\]\W\[\e[33m\]$(__repo)\[\e[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='\u@\h:\w$(__repo)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt

case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
  PS1="\[\e]0;\W\a\]$PS1"
  ;;
*)
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: @Alain, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest it's "How do I get it working on Mac?"

Comment: @blahdiblah Hmm, the editor suggests that it's  "Why doesn't this work on Mac?"

Comment: @Alain Damn!  I was so close!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mac OS X installations of Git don't have `__git_ps1` included.

Use:

```
alias __git_ps1="git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'"
```

as a substitution.

Comment: `\(*.*)/` hooray for grep `\(*.*)/`

Comment: Not a beautiful solution, but I had the same problem a while ago and this is what I found and put in my `.profile`. Probably I wasn't able to get a better one. I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: You can get the "full" definition of `__git_ps1` here. https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash  It's a bit heavy, but gives you nice information about rebasing, merging, etc.

Comment: In fact, the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) comes with `git-completion.bash` and installs it to `/usr/local/git/contrib/completion/`. Just source that file from your `.bash_profile` to get `__git_ps1`.

Comment: @sschuberth Thanks for the hint!  Looks like the prompt script has now been split out into `git-prompt.sh` found in the same directory as `git-completion.bash` (git version 1.8.3.4).

Answer (score 15):

The script you provided fails to detect git repos if the command `__git_ps1` fails. Add this to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

Assuming you stored the script file as `~/.ps1`, also add:

```
source ~/.ps1
```

---

- This solution also enables tab completion for git.
- [Mac OS X installations of git](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) *do* have __git_ps1 included, thanks sschuberth and cheapener for mentioning git-completion.bash.

Comment: My file was located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash. Mountain Lion with Xcode CLI installed.

Answer (score 12):

On a new Yosemite mac using built in git, I used this:

```
source /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
source /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
export PS1='\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\e[32;1m\]\u@\h:\w \[\e[33;1m\]$(__git_ps1 "[%s] ")\[\e[32;1m\]\$ \[\e[0m\]'
```

Note: on El Capitan, I had to change the path of the git scripts to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core` and I guess you have to have XCode installed for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed git through macports (git-core), you should add the following to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source /opt/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh
source /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
```

The location of the git-prompt.sh seemed to have changed a few times.