# (Mac) -bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: macos, git, terminal, ps1

I'm trying to change my command promt in terminal. I keep getting the error:

`-bash: __git_ps1: command not found`

I've tried it just by typing it into the terminal as is: `__git_ps1`. I've also tried it out in the `.bash_profile`

```
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash
  export PS1='[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi
```

As you might be able to see/tell, yes, I do have the auto-completion installed and it does work great!

I came across this question: " [PS1 env variable does not work on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435117/ps1-env-variable-does-not-work-on-mac) " which gives the code

`alias __git_ps1="git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'"`

So I add it to my `.bash_profile` hoping that it will change something. Well, it did. It just changed the error output.

Here's the `.bash_profile` with the addition:

```
alias __git_ps1="git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'"

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash
  export PS1='[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi
```

And now here's the changed error output:

`sed: (%s): No such file or directory`

***Note:*** I've also moved the alias below the source with no difference. I have *git version 1.7.12.1*

This should be a simple change. Can someone please help me?

**Edit 10/13/12**

No, I definitely do not want to define __git_ps1 myself but was just trying to see if it would be recognized by doing so. Yes, I have the `.git-completion.bash` file installed. Here's how I got auto completion on my machine.

```
cd ~
curl -OL https://github.com/git/git/raw/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
mv ~/git.completion.bash ~/.git-completion.bash
```

A `ls -la` then lists the `.git-completion.bash` file.

Comment: My `git-completion.bash` defines `__git_ps1` as a shell function.  Does yours?  How do you know completion is working?  What happens when you type `git h`<TAB>?

Comment: When I type that, it ends up with git help[space]

Comment: The accepted answer is good but the prompt can also be enabled by hitting `git <tab>` as noted in the commit referenced by Mark Longair.

Comment: That's not only a good explicate question, but also a helpful resource guiding to the solution. A well deserved upvote.

Comment: The -f check worked to fix this error when running bash inside of screen(1) on OS X 10.8.5. No idea why, since the file existed regardless, but thanks none the less!

Comment: I added in .bashrc and then it started working. Strange!

Answer (score 360, accepted):

You've installed the version of `git-completion.bash` from `master` - in git's development history this is after a commit that split out the `__git_ps1` function from the completion functionality into a new file (`git-prompt.sh`).  The commit that introduced this change, which explains the rationale, is [af31a456](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af31a456b4cd38f2630ed8e556e23954f806a3cc).

I would still suggest that you just source the version of `git-completion.bash` (or `git-prompt.sh`) that is bundled with your installation of git.

However, if for some reason you still want to use this functionality by using scripts separately downloaded from `master`, you should download `git-prompt.sh` similarly:

```
curl -o ~/.git-prompt.sh \
    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

... and add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
```

Then your `PS1` variable that includes `__git_ps1 '%s'` should work fine.

Geoff reported 10/13/12 adding the following to their `.bash_profile` worked while others did not:

```
if [ -f ~/.git-prompt.sh ]; then
  source ~/.git-prompt.sh
  export PS1='Geoff[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi
```

Comment: You're right that I don't want to define __git_ps1 myself. I was just trying to see if it would recognize it and it does not. I do have .git-completion.bash on my root. I'll update my question above to include how I got auto completion working...

Comment: @designer84: thanks for the extra information - I think it's clear now what the problem is, and I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Why does this not work? if [ -f /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash ]; then
  source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
  export PS1='[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi

Comment: @designer84: I'm glad to hear that worked.  The reason that including the version from your installed copy didn't work is that git 1.7.12.1 is after the split into `git-completion.bash` and `git-prompt.sh` that I described - there should also be a `.git-prompt.sh` in `/usr/local/git/contrib/completion/`

Comment: I have used you method Mark. Unfortunately the moment I enter a "git directory" when I normally had a branch displayed in the prompt... The all hell breaks loose... First bash starts to lag, later the whole computer until it's gone and restart is necessary... Any idea?

Comment: @op1ekun: sorry, I'm not sure, I'm afraid - unless you've set one of these environment variables: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L38 and the repository is a particularly large one. With those variables unset (the defaults) `__git_ps1` should be very light and fast independent of the repository, but they would cause more work to be done if set.

Comment: On OSX 10.9 with git 1.8.5.3 installed via Homebrew, both `git-prompt.sh` and `git-completion.bash` are found in `\`brew --prefix git\`/etc/bash_completion.d/`.

Comment: Note: You must restart Terminal to make changes take effect. It took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: In MacPorts, the path changed when the package `git-core` was replaced by `git`, see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/769439/why-doesnt-git-ps1-work-in-bash-anymore-on-osx-with-macports)

Comment: @YannisDran you can `source` the config file to avoid reloading the terminal.

Comment: On OSX 10.10.4 with git 2.4.5 installed via Homebrew, both `git-prompt.sh` and `git-completion.bash` are found in `\`brew --prefix git\`/etc/bash_completion.d/` , just like on OSX 10.9 as @dokkaebi mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: This would ommit the current directory in Mac OS X. So, I use `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }__git_ps1 '\u:\w' '\\\$ '"`

Comment: I still get an error: **bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found**

Comment: Thanks to @dokkaebi, this works for me (macOS): `source "\`brew --prefix git\`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh"`

Answer (score 61):

After upgrading to OSX 10.9 Mavericks I had to reference the following files to get git shell command completion and git prompt to work again.

From my .bash_profile or similar:

```
if [ -f /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
fi

source /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh

#shell prompt example
PS1='\u $(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\$ '
```

Comment: This was also my problem in osv 10.9

Comment: While the accepted response from @marklongair is a good description, I found this question via a Google search of an error message (after upgrading to OS 10.10) and this answer is the simplest solution for my issue (simply changing the path to the new location).

Comment: This worked for me in 10.10.5 Yosemite, however I changed the location of git-prompt to `~/.git_prompt.sh`. The other solutions didn't work.

Comment: I added your suggested lines to **.bash_profile**, but am still getting the error: `bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found`

Answer (score 43):

You should

$ brew install bash bash-completion git

Then source "$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion" in your .bashrc.

Comment: Great answer, definitely the best way if git is installed with brew. But i think you need to source this: source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh

Comment: @febLey Yes, the location changed. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I get errors: **bash: /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh: Permission denied
bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found**

Answer (score 14):

Following worked for me like a charm:

Run following in your Terminal:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh > ~/.bash_git
```

Open/Create bash_profile:

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Add following to the file:

```
source ~/.bash_git
export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]os \[\033[01;34m\]\w $(__git_ps1 "[%s]")\$\[\033[00m\] '
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
```

Finally, source it using:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

This will solve the problem of `bash: __git_ps1: command not found`.

Also your prompt will change to "os  ". To change "os" to something else, modify "os" string in export PS1 line.

Comment: I still get an error **sh -c "clear && /bin/bash"
bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found** every time I enter Docker CLI.

Answer (score 8):

## Solution for MacOS Sierra and git version 2.10.1 <2017-2-06>

### Step 1: Install the Git

#### You can skip this step if you already installed the latest git.

> Download git package from browser https://git-scm.com/download/

*Note: if you install with `curl [option] https://...` option to download, you would have to make sure your system support SSL. So for new comer, to download from browser and install directly from git installer is much easier.*

Installation Verification:

- Show where is your git directory at: `which git`
- Show which version your git currently is: `git --version` current version should be 2.10.1.

### Step 2: Add your git profile to your shell

1. Open your shell profile:

   - **`nano ~/.bash_profile`** or **`nano ~/.bashrc`** Depends on where your modification is.
2. Add the following code to the file:

   - **`source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash`**
   - **`source /usr/local/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`**

*Note: git installation location changed from opt/ directory to usr/local/ after OSX upgrade to El Capitain, and this is why some of the old answer above doesn't work anymore in MacOS Sierra.*

3. Add the following code to your PS1 configuration:

   - Option 1: add directly to your PS1: **`export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '`**

     I prefer this simple approach since I already know the `.git-completion.bash` is there in my home directory, and I can add other prompt format in the front of it. here is my personal prompt for your reference: `export PS1='\t H#\! \u:\w$(__git_ps1 "{%s}") -->> '`
   - Option 2: Add a selection script

   ```
   if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
         export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '
   fi
   ```
4. Save and use the profile: `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.bashrc`

Now you should see the git prompt working properly and shows which branch you are in right now.

Answer (score 6):

High Sierra clean solution with colors !

No downloads. No brew. No Xcode

Just add it to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

```
export CLICOLOR=1
[ -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh ] && . /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="auto"
PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\h:\W \u" "\\\$ "'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem when upgrading to Yosemite.

I just had to modify `~/.bashrc` to `source /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh` instead of the old path.

then re-source your `. ~/.bashrc` to get the effect.

Answer (score 4):

__git_ps1 for bash is now found in git-prompt.sh in /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d on my brew installed git version 1.8.1.5

Answer (score 2):

this works in OS 10.8 in the .bash_profile

```
if [ -f ~/.git-prompt.sh ]; then
  source ~/.git-prompt.sh
  export PS1='YOURNAME[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the error: **bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found**

Answer (score 2):

For macports I had to add: `source /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh` to my ./profile

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I guess you do not have **macports** installed? Simply do `touch ~/.profile`. But you obviously need a file in: /opt/local/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh

Answer (score 2):

If you're hoping to use Homebrew to upgrade Git and you've let your system become out-of-date in general (as I did), you may need to bring Homebrew itself up-to-date first (as per [brew update: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762859/brew-update-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by) thanks @chris-frisina)

**First bring Homebrew into line with the current version**

> cd /usr/local
>   git fetch origin
>   git reset --hard origin/master

**Then update Git:**

> brew upgrade git

*Problem Solved! ;-)*

Answer (score 2):

At least with Xcode 6, you already have `git-completion.bash`. It's inside the Xcode app bundle.

Just add this to your .bashrc:

```
source `xcode-select -p`/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the files **git-prompt.sh** and **git-completion.bash** from this [Git completion](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/completion)
2. Rename the files.
3. Move those files to your home directory.
4. Add  the source file in to the .bash_profile

   ```
   source ~/git-completion0.bash
   source ~/git-prompt0.sh
   and four to trigger the code block.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a real answer...

I had some strange issues with sourcing git-prompt.sh in my .bashrc so I started to look for other solution. This one: http://www.jqno.nl/post/2012/04/02/howto-display-the-current-git-branch-in-your-prompt/ doesn't use __git_ps1 and author claims it works also on Mac (for now it works perfectly on my Ubuntu and it's easy to tweak).

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the course on Udacity for git hub and was having this same issue. Here is my final code that make is work correctly.

```
# Change command prompt
alias __git_ps1="git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \ .   (.*\)/(\1)/'"

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
  source ~/.git-completion.bash
  export PS1='[\W]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)"): '
fi

source ~/.git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
# '\u' adds the name of the current user to the prompt
# '\$(__git_ps1)' adds git-related stuff
# '\W' adds the name of the current directory
export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"
```

It works!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0lvb.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Please not that, if you haven't installed git through Xcode or home-brew, you'll likely find the bash scripts haysclarks refers to in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/`, and not in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/`, thus making the lines to include within .bashrc the following:

```
if [ -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-completion.bash
fi

source /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
```

You'll need those lines if you wish to use git-prompt as well.
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20211241/4795986

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh -o ~/.git-prompt.bash

[[ -f ~/.git-prompt.bash ]]       && . ~/.git-prompt.bash
# Available GIT_PS1 options/env vars

cat ~/.git-prompt.bash | grep GIT_PS1_ | sed -r 's,^\s*#.*,,' | grep -v -E '^$' | sed -r 's,^.*(GIT_PS1_[A-Z_]+).*,\1,' | sort | uniq | sed -r 's,^(.*)$,export \1=,'
export GIT_PS1_COMPRESSSPARSESTATE=
export GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE=
export GIT_PS1_HIDE_IF_PWD_IGNORED=
export GIT_PS1_OMITSPARSESTATE=
export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=
export GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES=
export GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM=
export GIT_PS1_STATESEPARATOR=

for i in $(cat ~/.git-prompt.bash | grep GIT_PS1_ | sed -r 's,^\s*#.*,,' | grep -v -E '^$' | sed -r 's,^.*(GIT_PS1_[A-Z_]+).*,\1,' | sort | uniq); do varname=$i; declare -g ${i}=1; done
# P.S Above is just illustration not all config vars are [0/1].

# For more info: 

cat ~/.git-prompt.bash | sed -r -n -e '1,/^[^\s*#]/p' | head -n -2
```

Comment: A nice improvement could be to add the  just previous branch you were on in a dimmed state to the  prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me, and it has colored git output and an indicator in the prompt whether files have changed / been added, right baked into it:

```
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=true

. /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.2/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
. /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.2/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh

PS1='\[\033[32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[34m\]\w\[\033[31m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Be sure to use the correct path! I used homebrew to install git, use `brew list git` to get the path to your current installation.

Would be nice not to use a hard coded path, but don't know how to get the path to the current installation.

More infos here: http://en.newinstance.it/2010/05/23/git-autocompletion-and-enhanced-bash-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

For git, there are `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh`. And please look `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` too.

So, I put these in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh ]; then
  . /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/git-prompt.sh
  export GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS=1
  export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
  PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }__git_ps1 '\u:\w' '\\\$ '"
fi
```

Comment: Still getting this error: `bash: __docker_machine_ps1: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option I just installed on Mojave: [magicmonty/bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt#installation)

Run (`brew update`) and `brew install bash-git-prompt` or `brew install --HEAD bash-git-prompt`

Then to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh" ]; then
  __GIT_PROMPT_DIR=$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share
  GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO=1
  source "$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share/gitprompt.sh"
fi
```

I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Download the following files and copy them to home directory: `~/`

[git-completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

[git-prompt.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)

For the bash_profile, add this at the beginning:

```
source ~/git-completion.bash
source ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
```

[For more and easy downloads you could check this](https://github.com/MAlhussaini/terminal_coloring).