# -bash: __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: bash, shell, command, git-bash, ruby-2.0

I tried to install Ruby 2.0. My command line urped and now looks like the following:

```
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
[11:58:28][whatever@whatever ~]$
```

I have not a clue how to get rid of the `__git_ps1: command not found` error. I've searched my `.bash_profile` and my `.bashrc` to see if it's trying to set a variable or something and am not seeing anything. The only place I can find `git_ps1` mentioned is in `~/.dotfiles/.bash_prompt`. I  replace the content of that file completely, logout and log back in and it fixes nothing.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870928/mac-bash-git-ps1-command-not-found), but I'm pretty new to command line so I just confused myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of git are you using?

Comment: take a look https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147462

Comment: git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)

Comment: RESOLVED AT: https://gist.github.com/scottious/0d99ea77daa041b28929

Answer (score 33, accepted):

BASH has a whole slew of ways of automatically setting your prompt to give you nice information. You set the prompt by setting the `PS1` environment variable. For example, if I set `PS1="$ "` my prompt will look like this:

```
$
```

Not too informative. All I can tell is that the command line is prompting me.

However, If I set `PS1=\u@\h: \w$`, my prompt will now look like this:

```
david@vegibank:/usr/bin$
```

That tells me how I'm logged in (the `\u`), the machine I'm onto (`\h`), and the directory I'm in (the `\w`). If I use `git`, it would be nice if the git branch I'm in is also part of my prompt.

This is exactly what is going on with your `.profile`, your `.bashrc` file, your `.bash_login` or your `.bash_profile` script. Or, what some system admin did in `/etc/profile`.

There are a couple things you can do. Either:

- Download the missing `__git_ps1` and make sure it's in your `$PATH` environment variable (which is set by a combination of the various initialization files mentioned above)
- Change your `PS1` environment variable in whatever initialization file is being executed (I believe it is probably `.bash_profile`.

Just add this as the last line:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\n$ "
```

The added `\n` prints the dollar sign prompt on the line below like this:

```
david@vegibank:/usr/bin
$
```

I like to do that because the prompt can get rather long and editing the command line gets tricky when the prompt is longer than 30 to 50 characters. Otherwise, it's pretty much the standard prompt that most users use. You can see more about setting BASH prompts in the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). (Search for the word Prompting on that page).

If you find it a bit confusing, be glad you're not using Kornshell. I use Kornshell and to get the same prompt `PS1=\u@\h:\w\n$` does, I set my prompt as:

```
export PS1='$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")'
```

Comment: I added this to the last line of my BP and it's at least not breaking now. Will keep trying to figure out why I can't curl the below and make that work, too. Thanks all.

Comment: Just go into Git and manually download the file. Go to https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh in a browser, and click on the ***Raw*** button. Then cut and paste.

Comment: The question was about "__git_ps1" that is declared in git-prompt.sh. The @emil-lundberg answer is the right answer

Comment: @Metal3d Actually, the question was about the _command not found_ error in the OP's messed up prompt, and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 154):

Run the following:

```
$ curl -L https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh > ~/.bash_git
```

And add this to the top of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bash_git
```

Re-login to your shell and you should be set.

Comment: Blake, I get this:
    curl: (3) <url> malformed

Comment: If you have git installed locally (at least on Fedora), the git-prompt.sh script is included with the git distribution at `/usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`

Comment: @AlexJordan much the same holds under Arch: `/usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh`

Comment: On Debian Jessie it's called `git-sh-prompt` and is at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`

Answer (score 59):

Search your system for a `git-prompt.sh`, you need to `source` that for the `__git_ps1` function to be available. In Arch, it is currently located at `/usr/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh`. Add

```
source /path/to/git-prompt.sh
```

to some suitable shell script. If you're unsure where, add it to your `~/.bashrc`.

If you have `locate` installed, you can use that to find the `git-prompt.sh` file, but you may need to run `updatedb` as root first.

Comment: This is the GOOD answer, add this in ~/.bashrc BEFORE the PS1 export

"source /usr/share/git-core/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh" without quotes

Comment: This worked on debian stretch, i installed git-core and i had no `git-prompt.sh` or `completion` folder.

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04, the line is `source /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt`.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`:

```
# This script allows you to see repository status in your prompt.
#
# To enable:
#
#    1) Copy this file to somewhere (e.g. ~/.git-prompt.sh).
#    2) Add the following line to your .bashrc/.zshrc:
#        source ~/.git-prompt.sh
#    3a) Change your PS1 to call __git_ps1 as
#        command-substitution:
#        Bash: PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
#        ZSH:  setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
#        the optional argument will be used as format string.
#    3b) Alternatively, for a slightly faster prompt, __git_ps1 can
#        be used for PROMPT_COMMAND in Bash or for precmd() in Zsh
#        with two parameters, <pre> and <post>, which are strings
#        you would put in $PS1 before and after the status string
#        generated by the git-prompt machinery.  e.g.
#        Bash: PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
#          will show username, at-sign, host, colon, cwd, then
#          various status string, followed by dollar and SP, as
#          your prompt.
#        ZSH:  precmd () { __git_ps1 "%n" ":%~$ " "|%s" }
#          will show username, pipe, then various status string,
#          followed by colon, cwd, dollar and SP, as your prompt.
#        Optionally, you can supply a third argument with a printf
#        format string to finetune the output of the branch status
```

Following these steps should fix your issue!!

Answer (score 6):

As of 2019, the prompt helper function should be installed when installing the `git` package and can be found at `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`.

If it is not loaded, install `bash-completion` package and have a look into your `~/.bashrc`.

In my case I had to uncomment this:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

and open a new shell, and all was well.

Root cause was 'bash-completion` not being set up properly in the first place on a fresh install.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it simply using

```sh
sudo apt install git
```

This appears because git is not installed and therefore the environment variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Running
`source /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/git`
worked for me on Ubuntu-like distro with `git version 2.17.1`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove **gitfast** plugin from `~/.zshrc`

```
+ plugins=(git vscode laravel emoji timer zsh-autosuggestions gitfast)
- plugins=(git vscode laravel emoji timer zsh-autosuggestions)
```