# How can I fix the command line error when running sudo su?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

```
$ sudo su
sh: prompt_git: command not found
```

I get the following result on running sudo su. I've looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398153/4095653
This is in relation to the question: [How can I install Jekyll on OSX 10.11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567029/how-can-i-install-jekyll-on-osx-10-11)

Comment: You changed users, so instead of looking for prompt_git or whatever in your user's directories, you're telling bash to look in root's directories.

Comment: Try `sudo su -` or `sudo -i`?

Comment: You rarely need to be root forever. Consider running `sudo <your command>` instead of logging in as root. It's slightly inconvenient in the case of multiple arbitrary commands, but all implementations of `sudo` that I've seen persists the authentication status for your session for a few minutes, which means you'll only have to type your password once in a while, rather than every invocation.

Comment: @Palpatim I'm trying to install Jekyll using `sudo gem install jekyll` but I get the error `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/jekyll`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567029/how-can-i-install-jekyll-on-osx-10-11
Someone suggested I first run as root.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run `sudo su -` ?

Comment: @MusannifZahir After I run `sudo su` and `sudo gem install jekyll` I get the same error : `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/jekyll`

Comment: @AkashSubramanian I meant adding the `-` after the `sudo su` command. Run `sudo su -`

Comment: @MusannifZahir I tried `sudo su -` and `sudo -i` previously to no avail.

Comment: @AkashSubramanian you'll have to check the permissions of `jekyll` / `/usr/local` - if it's giving permissions issues as root, it could be a directory not having execute permissions

Comment: @MusannifZahir I just checked my `bin` and `local` have root and execute permissions set