# Git bash errors upon opening

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

When I open git bash I get the following message:

```
bash: __gitps1: command not found
[markd@LAPTOP-45NDNEGM ~]$
```

I can't seem to use git bash at all, but git cmd works fine. Unfortunately I can't gennerate an ssh key without git bash so I can't use git at all. I've uninstalled git several times and I have no idea how to fix the issue. When I search for similar errors I see "git_ps1", but I'm getting "gitps1". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/15384025/1860929

Comment: It shouldn't prevent you from using bash. You get an error message setting the prompt, but if your `$PS1` contains something like `'$(__gitps1)`, it will just pretend the output as the empty string. It's annoying (and fixable), but you still have a working shell.

Comment: Thank you @KeithThompson! I must have screwed something up when I wrote my ssh request because it threw an error and I assumed I had a bigger issue.