# bash: git_prompt: command not found

Tags: bash

I'm getting this Annoying `git_prompt: command not found` error. I got a new Mac, and I'm trying to use my old `.bash_profile` into the new computer. I used [Thoughtbot's laptop](https://github.com/thoughtbot/laptop) configuration which worked well last time.

I'm running on Mac Os Sierra, here is my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Configuring Our Prompt
# ======================

  # if you install git via homebrew, or install the bash autocompletion via homebrew, you get __git_ps1 which you can use in the PS1
  # to display the git branch.  it's supposedly a bit faster and cleaner than manually parsing through sed. i dont' know if you care
  # enough to change it

  # This function is called in your prompt to output your active git branch.
  function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
  }

  # This function builds your prompt. It is called below
  function prompt {
    # Define some local colors

    local   LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]" # really understood
    local        CHAR="theAsteve  :"    local   BLUE="\[\e[0;49;34m\]"

    # ♥ ☆ - Keeping some cool ASCII Characters for reference

    # Here is where we actually export the PS1 Variable which stores the text for your prompt
    export PS1="theAsteve$  "
      PS2='> '
      PS4='+ '
    }

  # Finally call the function and our prompt is all pretty
  prompt


  export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH"

  export GIT_MERGE_AUTOEDIT='no'

    # Editors
    # Tells your shell that when a program requires various editors, use sublime.
    # The -w flag tells your shell to wait until sublime exits
    export VISUAL="vim"
    export SVN_EDITOR="vim"
    export GIT_EDITOR="vim"
    export EDITOR="vim"

    # Version
    # What version of the Flatiron School bash profile this is
  # Paths

    # The USR_PATHS variable will just store all relevant /usr paths for easier usage
    # Each path is seperate via a : and we always use absolute paths.

    # A bit about the /usr directory
    # The /usr directory is a convention from linux that creates a common place to put
    # files and executables that the entire system needs access too. It tries to be user
    # independent, so whichever user is logged in should have permissions to the /usr directory.
    # We call that /usr/local. Within /usr/local, there is a bin directory for actually
    # storing the binaries (programs) that our system would want.
    # Also, Homebrew adopts this convetion so things installed via Homebrew
    # get symlinked into /usr/local
    export USR_PATHS="/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin"

    # Hint: You can interpolate a variable into a string by using the $VARIABLE notation as below.

    # We build our final PATH by combining the variables defined above
    # along with any previous values in the PATH variable.

    # Our PATH variable is special and very important. Whenever we type a command into our shell,
    # it will try to find that command within a directory that is defined in our PATH.
    # Read http://blog.seldomatt.com/blog/2012/10/08/bash-and-the-one-true-path/ for more on that.
    export PATH="$USR_PATHS:$PATH"

    # If you go into your shell and type: echo $PATH you will see the output of your current path.
    # For example, mine is:
    # /Users/avi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/avi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/avi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/avi/.rvm/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:

# Helpful Functions
# =====================

# A function to CD into the desktop from anywhere
# so you just type desktop.
# HINT: It uses the built in USER variable to know your OS X username

# USE: desktop
#      desktop subfolder
function desktop {
  cd /Users/$USER/Desktop/$@
}

# A function to easily grep for a matching process
# USE: psg postgres
function psg {
  FIRST=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/^\(.\).*/\1/'`
  REST=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/^.\(.*\)/\1/'`
  ps aux | grep "[$FIRST]$REST"
}

#==================================
# GOLANG PATH
#=================================
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go/bin/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

# A function to extract correctly any archive based on extension
# USE: extract imazip.zip
#      extract imatar.tar
function extract () {
    if [ -f $1 ] ; then
        case $1 in
            *.tar.bz2)  tar xjf $1      ;;
            *.tar.gz)   tar xzf $1      ;;
            *.bz2)      bunzip2 $1      ;;
            *.rar)      rar x $1        ;;
            *.gz)       gunzip $1       ;;
            *.tar)      tar xf $1       ;;
            *.tbz2)     tar xjf $1      ;;
            *.tgz)      tar xzf $1      ;;
            *.zip)      unzip $1        ;;
            *.Z)        uncompress $1   ;;
            *)          echo "'$1' cannot be extracted via extract()" ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "'$1' is not a valid file"
    fi
}


# Bash completion has been installed to:
# /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

[[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"

# Case-Insensitive Auto Completion
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"

# Postgres
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH


  if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
  fi

# ===============================================================
# History
# ===============================================================
# Larger bash history
export HISTSIZE=32768
export HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE

# ---------------------
# Colors
# ---------------------

# Adds colors to LS
export CLICOLOR=1
# http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/
export LSCOLORS=bxexcxdxbxegedabagacad
# prompt colors
BLACK="\[\e[0;30m\]"
RED="\033[1;31m"
ORANGE="\033[1;33m"
GREEN="\033[1;32m"
PURPLE="\033[1;35m"
WHITE="\033[1;37m"
YELLOW="\[\e[0;33m\]"
CYAN="\[\e[0;36m\]"
BLUE="\[\e[0;34m\]"
BOLD=""
RESET="\033[m"


#----------------------
# style the prompt
# ---------------------
style_user="\[${RESET}${WHITE}\]"
style_path="\[${RESET}${CYAN}\]"
style_chars="\[${RESET}${WHITE}\]"
style_branch="${RED}"

# A more colorful prompt
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
c_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
#  \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_path='\[\e[0;31m\]'
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
c_git_clean='\[\e[0;32m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_git_dirty='\[\e[0;31m\]'

# ---------------------
# Build the prompt
# ---------------------
# Example with committed changes: username ~/documents/GA/wdi on master[+]

__GIT_PROMPT_DIR=$(brew --prefix)/opt/bash-git-prompt/share

[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion || {
    # if not found in /usr/local/etc, try the brew --prefix location
    [ -f "$(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash" ] && \
        . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
}

source ~/.bash_git

# PS1 is the variable for the prompt you see everytime you hit enter

PS1+="${style_user}\u"                   # Username
PS1+="${style_path} \w"                  # Working directory
PS1+="\$(prompt_git)"                    # Git details
PS1+="\n"                                # Newline
PS1+="${style_chars}\$ \[${RESET}\]"     # $ (and reset color)
export PS1='\t H#\! \u:\w$(__git_ps1 "{%s}") -->> '
```

I tried some of the other posts regarding the same issue. I tried going over the following code without success. [-bash: __git_ps1: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384025/bash-git-ps1-command-not-found/17508424)

At

Comment: So install the executable/program/whatever it is caled`git_prompt`, it does no exists on your system. Command is not found.

Comment: I installed it. In many different ways

Comment: You did not, it failed, it installed to the wrong directory or was not added to your `$PATH`. Where is `git_prompt` then? When you are getting the error?

Comment: ` /usr/local/Cellar/bash-git-prompt/2.7.1`

Comment: Did you add the things as described in the [repo](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt)

Comment: maybe the position where is at? I'll take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this feature for years and this works when adding to the bottom of ~/.bashrc

Setup & Config source: https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt

```
function parse_git_branch () {
git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
NO_COLOR="\[\033[0m\]"
PS1="$GREEN\u@\h$NO_COLOR:\w$YELLOW\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOR\$ "
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
user@server:~/dev/project (Some-Branch-Feature)$
```

You will have to toy around with it to your liking but hope it gets you somewhere.

Comment: Im adding `PS1=` in `.bash_profile` would I have to delete it and move it to `.bashrc`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the gitawareprompt configurations in my `.bash_profile`. The reason why you want it in there is because you would like it to be applied every time you open a new terminal or iterm session. Understandable. Years ago, I decided to add `source ~/.bashrc` at the top of my ~/.bash_profile and so that it automatically loads all my .bashrc configs when I launch new terminals. This may not be what others do but I'm a pretty avid CLI user and my hack works fine for me. You would have to `source ~/.bash_profile` and `source ~/.bashrc` to get the connection kickstarted. Try it out!

Comment: I also just tried testing adding just the PS1= in my .bash_profile and gitawareprompt in .bashrc , sourced ~/.bashrc but it didn't like it. The method above works fine for me. On linux servers, I just have the block above added to the bottom of .bashrc and it has no issues. I don't need to add ~/.bashrc to ~/.bash_profile either.