# Unknown error in Bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I restarted my computer (Mac running Yosemite) earlier today and when I opened Terminal and run any command I keep seeing the following error:

```
-bash: __git_ps1: command not found
```

I googled around but couldn't find any documentation about this issue and was wondering if someone has seen this before and how you were able to make the alert go away.

Comment: see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870928/mac-bash-git-ps1-command-not-found

Comment: This means you have software installed which is trying to include status from `git` in your prompt, but some shell functions it depends on aren't defined.

Comment: @swang, shoot -- I wish I'd seen that before voting with a different close reason; this is indeed an exact duplicate.

Comment: Shoot, sorry for the duplicate question. For some reason that Stack question didn't show up when I was googling. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.