# Unable to see git branch in mac terminal prompt

Tags: git, bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to add the git branch to my Terminal prompt by editing the bash profile but cannot determine why it's not working--haven't been able to apply the answers to any of the other posted questions. Here is what is in my profile now:

```
if  [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh ]; then
    source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt.sh
    GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
    PS1='\w$(__git_ps1) \n\$ '
fi
```

For the record, when I ran brew `install bash-completion`, it did not create git-prompt.sh in the bash_completion.d directory.

Comment: What do you get if you call `__git_ps1` in your shell?

Comment: That's your problem then. Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871094/57095

Comment: OK, that helped--when I added that line to my bash profile, `__git_ps1` now functions and provides a response, but the branch itself still doesn't appear in my prompt, I have to run the command. Do I need to update the path in the code I posted? Also thanks for the help.

Comment: Make sure that the body of the `if` gets executed, also you might want to source your `~/.bashrc`. I'm not sure about the branch name, I don't use `__git_ps1`, I've built a custom prompt over the years.