# posh-git not working with Pycharm: "bash: __git_ps1: command not found"

Tags: terminal, pycharm, bash, posh-git

I have been using the same bash_profile for years with terminal, which includes posh-git.
https://github.com/lyze/posh-git-sh

However, when I started using Pycharm, the editor's terminal doesn't render my posh-git, but instead gives me the error:

`bash: __git_ps1: command not found`

This is my bash_profile:

`source ~/develop/git-prompt.sh
 PROMPT_COMMAND='__posh_git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ ";'$PROMPT_COMMAND
 PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

I tried adding `PS1="\u@\h:\w\n$ "` as some have suggested, but to no avail.

How can I get my posh-git to work in pycharm and not have this error?

Comment: How do you start Pycharm?

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870928/mac-bash-git-ps1-command-not-found). I had a similar problem and it resolved it.